# Dynamics CRM: WCF Security Error after forcing TLS 1.2

Tags: c#, wcf, dynamics-crm, wcf-binding, wcf-security

We have a functional WCF connection to our Dynamics CRM (2016 on-premise). We recently needed to remove SSL 2.0/3.0 and TLS 1.0/1.1 on the Dynamics server in order to meet compliance (force TLS 1.2). This broke our WCF connection. We would see the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Metadata contains a reference that
>   cannot be resolved:
>   'https://DynamicsURL.com/OrgName/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc?wsdl'.
>   ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException:
>   Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing
>   connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was
>   forcibly closed by the remote host

I did not configure this and im no code export, but as far as i can tell, the connection security is all in the web.config and needs to be adjusted. It looks like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IWCFService" sendTimeout="00:25:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://DynamicsURL.com:8080/WCF/wcfservice.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IFWCFService" contract="WCF.IWCFService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IWCFService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel
```

The issue started after implementing the following changes:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\Multi-Protocol Unified Hello\Client]
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\Multi-Protocol Unified Hello\Server]
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\PCT 1.0]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\PCT 1.0\Client]
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\PCT 1.0\Server]
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0\Client]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001
"Enabled"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0\Server]
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 3.0]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 3.0\Client]
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 3.0\Server]
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Client]
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Server]
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Client]
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Server]
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client]
"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server]
"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
```

**Update**

I tried the following system.serviceModel config in the web.config of the client app calling the WCF app, and im getting the following error:

> The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.

```
    <system.serviceModel>  
        <bindings>  
            <wsHttpBinding>  
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IWCFService">  
                    <security mode="Transport">  
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />  
                    </security>  
                </binding>  
            </wsHttpBinding>  
        </bindings>  
          <client>
      <endpoint address="https://DynamicsURL.com:8080/WCF/WCFService.svc" 
      binding="wsHttpBinding" 
      bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IWCFService" 
      contract="WCF.IWCFService" 
      name="BasicHttpBinding_IWCFService" />
    </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

**Update 3**

As mentioned below, i resolved the issue by adding the Reg value showing below. However, im now facing other issues. I was using [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest) to scan my site, and i scored a B. The solution was to enable and prefer the **TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384** and **TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256** chiper. Doing that, resulted SSLLabs complaining about DH, so i set that to 2048. Now it seems all good, but im getting hammered with `Schannel` errors (below).I found some suggestions to enable the **Use FIPS** security settings, but when i do that, it breaks a number of functions (Dynamics CRM Plugins) i have running on that machine. For example, the plugin would fail with this error: `Error Occurred in Plugin NameRemoved exception: This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms.` Others suggestions was to remove **TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384** and **TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256** chiper, but i cant remove it for the grading. As its now, everything seems to functioning properly besides the errors.

**Errors**

> - A fatal alert was generated and sent to the remote endpoint. This may result in termination of the connection. The TLS protocol defined fatal error code is 20. The Windows SChannel error state is 960.
> - A fatal error occurred while creating an SSL client credential. The
>     internal error state is 10013.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v2.0.50727]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v2.0.50727]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.5.1]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.5.23026]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v2.0.50727]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you should be using port 80 or port 8080.  See following : https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/enable-https-tls-with-8080-port-on-url/76280.  I would also check the IE Advance Settings to see if the right version of TLS/SSL are checked.

Comment: Its configured to use port 8080. I could tell you that i have no issues going to that URL on the server which is trying to establish the WCF connection using any browser.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Microsoft documentation: [Transport Layer Security (TLS) best practices with the .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls#for-wcf-using-net-framework-35---452-using-tcp-transport-security-with-certificate-credentials)

> **For WCF using .NET Framework 3.5 - 4.5.2 using TCP transport security with Certificate Credentials**
>
> These versions of the WCF framework are hardcoded to use values SSL 3.0 and TLS 1.0. These values cannot be changed. You must update and retarget to NET Framework 4.6 or later versions to use TLS 1.1 and 1.2.

Looks like you may need to upgrade you WCF services to .NET Framework to 4.6.2 or above.

Comment: Its currently 4.6

Answer (score 0):

First, your client connection doesn’t configure the Https service address properly.

```
<binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IWCFService" 

bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IFWCFService"
```

Also, Based on the TLS Best practices with Dotnet Framework.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls
we should not interfere with the decision of underlying TLS version.

> Do not specify the TLS version. Configure your code to let the OS
>   decide on the TLS version.

Per your description, in order to achieve the TLS1.2 communications over HTTPS, we should upgrade the Dotnetframework SDK version to 4.6.1 above before we have configured the HTTPS service endpoint on the server-side.
Then on the client-side, we install Dotnetframework4.6 above too. And specify the TLS version by using the following code before making a call to the server.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

We could check the practical TLS version by using Wireshark.
[image]
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Thanks for your response Abraham. For good measure, i recomplied both my WCF app and frontend app (making the WCF call) using 4.7. After lots of fighting with this and dealing with the rebuild issues, package upgrading, incompatible libraries and references, i was able able to successfully rebuild. The issue is still not resolved

`[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm]`

Comment: I should also mentioned that im not specifying the TLS version in the code. The code is pointing to an XML file which has all the settings, URL and Credentials

Comment: how did you configure WCF to enable https protocol on the server-side? I would like to know more details about the System.Servicemodel section in the configuration file. Besides, your client doesn't make sense, how could it possibly call the https service endpoint with a Basichttpbinding that using Securitymode=None(instead of transport)?

Comment: I tried another config (updated my original question with the details), and now i'm seeing this: `The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.`. What would be the proper configuration?

Comment: These configurations should be automatically generated by adding service reference instead of manually configuring it.
Which binding to use depends on your configuration on the server-side. Also, can you access the server’s metadata file correctly? The Url form like you mentioned above, ‘https://DynamicsURL.com/OrgName/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc?wsdl'.
(or maybe based on Http, independent of the actual communication protocol of the service). if not, I think the service is not configured properly on the server-side.

Comment: My solution was to add `"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001` to force .NET to use TLS 1.2. I added it to `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]` and `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v2.0.50727]`. However, im now facing other issues. Ill update the original question